# Opening Colorbox after function completes

Tags: jquery, colorbox

Im trying to open a colorbox lightbox after my existing function completes.

After my div has been shown and then hidden I want a lightbox window to open but I am really struggling to get it to open.  Can anyone shed any light on this.

This is the relevant bit of code

```
$(".bookingResult").addClass("classroomExpertError");
$(".bookingResult").html(obj.Message);
$('.bookingResult').show('slow', function()                     {
  setTimeout(function()
   {$('.bookingResult').hide('slow');
    }, 3000); // <-- time in milliseconds 
});
```

Comment: So, fade in -> fade out -> colorbox pop?

Comment: @Chris, I'm off topic, but - why the repeated selection using the booking result? Either chain the methods or cache the selector for more-better perf. ie var a = $('.bookingResult');

Answer (score 0):

[`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) both accept callbacks, they will fire after the effect completes. [Colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox) can be opened on command.

```
$('.bookingResult').show('slow', function() {
    $(this).hide('slow', function() {
        $.colorbox({href:"thankyou.html"});
    });
});
```

This might not be what you want though, as the callbacks will fire once for each matched element.